# Mimicking a bluetooth disconnection

Tags: testing

I've written a program to control a bluetooth device. I'm trying to test cases when the bluetooth disconnects, i.e. if its out of range.

Physically taking the device out of range is one possibility, but its quite cumbersome and I have to go outside my office to achieve this.

What can I do to trigger a disconnection? Is there, for example, an interferer I can setup, say with an Android phone, that would make the connection drop? Or limit the Bluetooth transmit power? Any other possibilities?

Comment: Perhaps wrap the bluetooth device in aluminum ? Basically some kind of a Faraday cage.

Comment: "... have to go outside my office to achieve this." - yes, and it creates kind of a large-scale [Schroedinger's cat paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) because whilst you are outside you can't see what your application does, and vice versa... :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to trigger a disconnect. I guess you are mostly interested in triggering a sudden loss of connection, not a graceful disconnect.

Some things that I have used in the past:

- Take the device out of range
- Remove the battery/power source (without doing a normal power down -> a sudden loss of power)
- Put the device in a shielded box/cage of Faraday

Bluetooth was designed to work in a frequency band with a lot of interference/noise, so it is unlikely you will be able to reliably trigger a disconnect that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I have approached a similar case in a Bluetooth application. The advantage is that you can test your application logic without actually using a device or having to setup a communication at all. This also means you can regression test much easier and faster.

1. Separate concerns

   Implement a `comms` module that handles the Bluetooth communication, i.e. connecting, sending, receiving data, disconnecting. This module translates each of these events into application-level `commands & responses` and passes these on to a `logic` module that processes them. This way, `logic` handles all the application logic, while `comms` handles the communication.
2. Build a simulator for the `comms` module, a.k.a `driver`. The simulator should act as the `comms` module would, i.e. generate and consume `commands & responses`. But since it is independent of any actual communication, you can control exactly what it does, and when, while the `logic` module thinks it actually talks to to real `comms` module.
3. Build unit tests that use the `driver` to create a controlled environment to test your `logic` module.

For example, one unit test could be like so (pseudo-code):

```
def test_disconnect():
   # create a new driver and attach it to the logic module
   driver = Driver()
   logic.attach(driver)
   # make a connection, then disconnect
   driver.connect()
   driver.disconnect()
   # check if logic has processed the disconnect
   # (assuming this produces an observable state)
   assert(logic.isDisconnected)
```